# How to constrain the Element type for an Array when it's the Element of another Array

Tags: arrays, swift, where-clause, associated-types

I have an array, within an array situation, and I want to constrain the internal Array's element type.

```
// this doesn't work but should illustrate what I want. Is there
// any way to constrain the Element type for an Array when it's
// already declared as the type for an Array 
extension Array where Element == Array<Element2: SomeProtocol> { 
}
```

Ultimately, I think that solving this problem will fix the following compile error

```
protocol Thingy {
    associatedtype MeasurementType: Measurement

    var topMeasurements: [[MeasurementType]] { get }
}

extension Thingy {
    func doStuff() {

        // COMPILE ERROR'[[Self.MeasurementType]]' is not convertible to 'Array<Array<Measurement>>'
        let compileError = self.topMeasurements.measurements(forUUIDs: ["A"])

        // Hack workaround
        // The fact that this works leads me to believe that the constraint in the
        // extension is inadequate. The extension wants [[Measurement]] and 
        // event though MeasurementType is a kind of Measurement the compiler won't 
        // allow it. The hope is that if we could write something like 
        // [[Element]] where Element: Measurement
        let measurements: [[Measurement]] = self.topMeasurements
        let thisWorks = measurements.doSomething(ids: ["A"])
        print(thisWorks)
    }
}

// I'm hoping that if I constrain the following that it'll fix my issue
// constrain this type ----------------------
//                                          |
//                                          \/
extension Array where Element == Array<Measurement> {
    func doSomething(ids: [String]) -> [Measurement] {
        // do something return some elements, 
        // I've removed any code that could cause confusion
        return []
    }
}
```

Comment: `measurements(forUUIDs:)` is really unclear. I see what the code is, and I still have no idea what it's doing.

Comment: I've changed measurements to doSomething(ids:) I hope that removes any confusion.

Comment: The confusion doesn't effect the question, it effects whoever next reads your code, which will most likely be yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is much easier to implement as an extension on all Collections rather than just on Arrays. I believe the extension you want is this:

```
extension Collection where Element: Collection, Element.Element: Measurement {
    func measurements(forUUIDs: [String]) -> [Measurement] {
        return []
    }
}
```

The basic problem is that Swift lacks higher-kinded types, so you can't extend `Array` (because that's not a proper type). But you can extend `Collection` (because that's a PAT).

Comment: PAT? I've never heard that term before. I tried searching for it but as you may have guessed I got a bunch of junk. What does PAT stand for?

Comment: @Biclops: A **P**rotocol with an **A**ssociated **T**ype

Comment: Here's another question that was spurred from this one. Maybe you could take a look at this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52305767/ambiguous-call-to-collection-extension-function