# Ambiguous call to Collection extension function

Tags: swift, collections, associated-types

The compiler is telling me that the

```
Expression type '([String]) -> Bool' is ambiguous without more context
```

I'm not sure how to add more context to the statement. I thought the Extension declaration would have told the function everything it needed about the elements in the collection. I've left more thoughts in the code snippet. Look for the area marked "!!! COMPILE ERROR !!!"

You should be able to copy and paste the code into an empty project to see the compile error.

```
protocol Measurement {
    var id: String { get }
    var displayPriority: Int { get }
}

extension Collection where Element: Collection, Element.Element: Measurement {
    func contains(ids: [String]) -> Bool {
        return self.filter{ measurementCollection -> Bool in
            // !!! COMPILE ERROR !!!
            // Error: Expression type '([String]) -> Bool' is ambiguous without more context
            //
            // The compiler doesn't under stand that this is a collection of Measurement,
            // Do I somehow need to tell the compiler that the elements to the collection 
            // or collections with elements with a type that is a kind of Measurement again?
            // I thought the extension declaration already specified everything it needed.
            return measurementCollection.isEquals(ids: ids)
        }.count > 0
    }
}


extension Collection where Element == Measurement {
    func isEquals(ids: [String]) -> Bool {
        // get all the IDs
        let allIDs = self.map{ $0.id }

        // convert it to a set to make comparisons easier
        return Set(allIDs) == Set(ids)
    }
}

func whatIwantToDo() {
    let measurements = [[ConcreteMeasurement("A")],
                        [ConcreteMeasurement("B")],
                        [ConcreteMeasurement("C"), ConcreteMeasurement("D")]
    ]

    let ids = ["C", "D"]
    // Ultimately, I want to fix my compile error to run the following line of code, this should output to True
    print("Does measurements contain: \(ids) -> \(measurements.contains(ids: ids))" )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first extension has the constraint `Element.Element: Measurement`, 
which means that in the closure, `measurementCollection` is a collection whose
element types *adopts* the `Measurement` protocol.

Therefore, in order to call the `isEquals()` method from the second extension on this collection, it must be defined as

```
extension Collection where Element: Measurement { // Not: Element == Measurement
    func isEquals(ids: [String]) -> Bool { ... }
}
```

Note also that generally, a test

```
filter { ... }.count > 0
```

is more efficiently done as

```
contains(where: { ... })
```

Comment: Damn it, I was getting tunnel vision. I should have known. Also thanks for the optimization tip.